# Apache POI corrupting file

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

I was trying to update an excel file in Selenium using Apache POI in java. But when i open the Excel file, it is showing corrupted.

Below is my Java Code.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.print.attribute.standard.JobHoldUntil;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.jboss.netty.util.internal.SystemPropertyUtil;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test_Copy_Write1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
// get Pace Content
        FileInputStream paceIn = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\News\\Prelim.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook paceWB = new XSSFWorkbook(paceIn);
        XSSFSheet paceSheet = paceWB.getSheetAt(0);
        ByteArrayOutputStream paceOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        XSSFWorkbook pOut = new XSSFWorkbook();

        int paceRows = paceSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        System.out.println("PACE Content start");
        chromeDriver.get("http://xyzwebsite.com/OpenPubSearch");
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("12345");
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("west");
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/input")).click();
        for (int i = 0; i < paceRows; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchPublication']")).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            }
            String DBName = paceSheet.getRow(i).getCell(7).toString();
            getPaceNumber(chromeDriver, DBName, paceSheet, i);
        }
        // Create a output file
        FileOutputStream paceOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\News\\Prelim.xlsx"));
        pOut.write(paceOutputStream);
        paceOutputStream.writeTo(paceOut);
        paceOut.close();


        chromeDriver.quit();
    }


private static void getPaceNumber(WebDriver chromeDriver, String dBID, XSSFSheet paceSheet, int i)
            throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/b/b/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/textarea")).sendKeys(dBID);
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/b/b/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input[1]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        String paceNumber = (String) chromeDriver
                .findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]")).getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println("Pace number is " + paceNumber.toString() + " For DB " + dBID);
        XSSFCell cell = null;
        XSSFRow sheetRow = paceSheet.getRow(i);
        // Update the value of cell
        cell = sheetRow.getCell(1);
        if (cell == null) {
            cell = sheetRow.createCell(1);
        }
        cell.setCellValue("Pass");
    }
}
```

Here I'm sorry not for providing the website URL. this is our organization's internal website.

please let me know how can i update my Excel sheet without corrupting it.

The console is printing the value correctly.

Thanks

Comment: You don't appear to be writing any content into your new workbook. You must create at least one sheet for a valid file

Comment: Hi @Gagravarr, I think that i'm writing `cell = sheetRow.getCell(1);
        if (cell == null) {
            cell = sheetRow.createCell(1);
        }
        cell.setCellValue("Pass");`, please let me know if i'm doing some mistake

Comment: Probably not directly related, but the access via getPhysicalNuymberOfRows() may cause trouble with some XLSX files, row-indices do not need to start at 0 and do not need to be continuous, easiest is to iterate of the rows with `for(Row row : paceSheet)`

Comment: And as Gagravarr mentioned, you fetch the `paceSheet` from the newly created document `paceWB`, NOT `paceIn`, so you do not have any rows to iterate over and thus do not write anything...

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for the suggestions, this fixed my issue, I forgot to create a cell ;), Thanks again